# How to Access CPanel MySql DB in other Host

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I have a Host enayam.in (linux) i have mysql db in this Host.

Actually i have to access it on my Localhost(With WAMP or MAMP)

if the Database in localhost(WAMP or MAMP) then i can connect my DB like this

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('testDB');
```

now i try to access my enayam.in DB in my localhost(WAMP or MAMP)

```
mysql_connect('enayam.in', 'enayamin_dbuser', 'enayamin_dbpassword');
mysql_select_db('enayamin_testDB');
```

but its giving error, i also try with my server IP as host (75.126.136.20)

```
mysql_connect('75.126.136.20', 'enayamin_dbuser', 'enayamin_dbpassword');
mysql_select_db('enayamin_testDB');
```

eventhough its giving error. please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error?
Have you added your own IP address in trsuted IPs in cPanel of your host? ( IPs which can connect to your DB remotely )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cPanel > Remote MySQL > Add your IP address. Use % as a wildcard ex. 64.65.54.%

Comment: I am using MAMP on Mac OS X. What would be my I.P? Sorry for late Reply!

Comment: Use the ip address of the machine you are trying to connect from. To find out what your ip address is go to www.whatismyip.com.

Answer (score 1):

To access a database from the local system, the **remote access** for your **db** has to be **enabled** in your server.

Just refer this link to **enable remote access** http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html